# Ruby on Rails User interface Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I would like to know list of  gems which is helpful for creating a very  good looking (user interface) application.

Comment: @user1402576 I would recommend twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say use the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) and then look over the [Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).